# My service doesn't change the wallpaper and I don't know why

Tags: c#, service

I've created a service, which "locks" the desktop background, so you can't change it. In general, the service compares the current wallpaper with the one I want to be the new wallpaper. If it's not the same, it gets overwritten. This is my OnTimer()-Method, which gets executed every 2 seconds:

```
private void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!File.Exists("C:/Program Files/image.jpg"))
    {
        Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        Stream s = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MsService.Gandalf.jpg"); ;
        byte[] b;

        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(s))
        {
            b = br.ReadBytes((int)s.Length);
        }

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes("C:/Program Files/image.jpg", b);
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //stuff
            }
        }
    }

    //{path} is %Appdata%
    if (!FileEquals($"{path}\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Themes\\TranscodedWallpaper", "C:/Program Files/image.jpg"))
    {
        byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes("C:/Program Files/image.jpg");

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes($"{path}\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Themes\\TranscodedWallpaper", file);
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's the FileEquals Method:

```
static bool FileEquals(string path1, string path2)
{
    byte[] file1 = File.ReadAllBytes(path1);
    byte[] file2 = File.ReadAllBytes(path2);
    if (file1.Length == file2.Length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < file1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (file1[i] != file2[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I start the service, It only changes the wallpaper if I change it actively, even if it already is another one that the one I want it to be, and only once. The service outputs no error when debugging, and the service doesn't crash. Also when I change the wallpaper, the breakpoints in the if(!File.Equals(...)) gets triggered. Virus scanner isn't alerting anything too. Why doesn't it work anyway?

Comment: probably to do with the fact that service doesn't run on user session

Comment: That changes nothing. Also it sometimes works for one time while being in a "LocalSystem" session

Comment: isn't service an overkill just wondering as opposed to implementing app monitoring

Comment: I don't get the use of your `while(true)` there, if you get an exception it will probably happens the next iteration and if you do not it will only run once. Why do you need it ?

Comment: I think we have to see the `FileEquals` method.